# vi moving lines and words

Tags: unix, vi, ex

I am taking a UNIX class, and unfortunately my teacher is not the greatest..So I am in need of your help!

I have a file named file1 with the text:

```
Roger Mancuso
Xavier Allen
Paul Bibbens
```

What our teacher wants us to do is with a single command first move the top line of the file to the bottom so it will look like:

```
Xavier Allen
Paul Bibbens
Roger Mancuso
```

And then using an ex command we have to take the first names, and move them after the last names, and separate them with a comma as such:

```
Allen, Xavier
Bibbens, Paul
Mancuso, Roger
```

Any help you guys could provide would be greatly appreciated, I tried going to my teachers office hours today to ask him about this and he basically told me to get lost, so now I have no idea what is going on..

Thank you so much!

Comment: And what have you tried...?

Comment: Well should probably tag this as homework. but take a look at help :m  for info on the move command for The first question)

Comment: I never knew about :m before that worked perfectly, I have been trying to do the same thing with awk for the past couple hours @Doon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:m $` - Move current line to bottom

`:%s/\v(\w*) (\w*)/\2, \1/g` - For second part

Answer (score 0):

What about this for the second part?

```
:%s/\(.*\)\, \(.*\)/\2, \1/g
```

parentheses save what they match into variables which you can access as \1 \2 \3 etc.